# Can I have different releases of the same app, one for the iPhone 4 Retina display and one for older devices?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'm working on an app with a considerable number of assets. Since the app has both assets for the Retina display and for a normal resolution, I think it will get close to 2 GB at the end of development.

Is it possible to release a build with support for the Retina display (including only the assets used by devices with a Retina display) and another build for older devices only (including only the assets used by devices *without* a Retina display)?

Edit: That would be the same that releasing a regular version and an HD version of my app ?, I'm not certain about this. I see that infinity blade only works for 3GS an onwards because it uses openGL 2.0.

Comment: For comparison, "The Elements: A Visual Exploration" is 1.71 GB.

Comment: IMHO I think that Apple should do this automatically. Since they have the 2x naming convention they could easily figure out whether a given file will ever be used on your device or not. There's no reason for downloading files that will never be used.

Comment: @Evan 1.71 GB compressed or uncompressed ?, I'm not sure if the 2GB limit is for a compressed or an uncompressed app

Comment: Compressed (Archived). https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf (CMD+F "2GB")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to have different release of the same app (same app bundle ID anyway). So you'd have to create a new app bundle for each different set of devices you wish to target.

Unfortunately from the documentation, it's not possible to specify display-type/display-scale as one of the options:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3

Have you considering including the bare minimum graphics needed to launch the app and have the user only download the assets they need after the app has launched?

Comment: I guess I'm gonna use different bundles for each version, like myGameHD for   iphone 4 and onwards, but the in app-purchasse option sounds A LOT better. I have used Store kit in the past but only for unlocking content already inside the app, never tried downloading content outside the app. I have a server, so that's a start :). Could you point me to any resources to start ?. and how does Apple exactly review that DLC ? ( my first guess is that during the review period they try to download the content themselves). Thanks !

Comment: Apple reviews screenshots and In-App purchases for each release. In iTunes connect you can associate in-app purchase items for a version so they appear when you launch a new app version, or you can just submit in-app content for review and it will get pushed out once it's approved. I think the first content you push out has to go out with a new app version. Also look at 3rd party providers such as Urban Airship to make your life easier.